# JS, Connect <h1> with <title>

Tags: javascript, html, css

All I want to do is to make the title the exact same as the h1 tag.

```
<title class="blogtitle"></title>
<h1 class="title">Updating our staff members</h1>

<script>
        document.getElementsByClassName("blogtitle")[0].innerHTML = h1;
        var h1 = document.getElementsByClassName("title")
</script>
```

Comment: That would be very bad for both SEO and accessibility. Don't use JS for this. Use a template engine that allows to do this on the server.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: For the most part, both search engines and screen readers parse the HTML that is transferred from the server to the browser, not the HTML that your Javascript has modified later on.

Comment: @connexo are u sure? Google etc are able to parse websites with js since a decade

Comment: Google is not the only search engine; I'm not exactly aware of how good screen readers are in this regard as of today. It's still much safer to not use JS for such SEO/accessibility-crucial parts like `title`.

Answer (score 2):

That would be very bad for both SEO and accessibility. Don't use JS for this. Use a template engine that allows to do this on the server.

That being said, here's the Javascript that would do this and which you shouldn't use if search engine optimization or accessibily is of any relevance in your project.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', // make sure this code only runs once JS can access the DOM safely
  function() { //
    document.title = document.querySelector('h1.title')?.textContent ?? '';
  }
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="title">Updating our staff members</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Instead of using the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) listener (which is only in place to make sure all the elements in the page are available for accessing via Javascript), you can also include your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="title">Updating our staff members</h1>
  <script>
    document.title = document.querySelector('h1.title')?.textContent ?? '';
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like you're just learning HTML and getting into this new universe. So I will just answer your question and not overload you with a bunch of advanced information.

You can change the title of a page by using

```
document.title = 'Your new title'
```

so you can do something along these lines:

```
var h1Element = document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0] // you can use other selectors here such as querySelector, getElementByClassName...
var h1Text = h1Element.innerHTML
document.title = h1Text
```

Also, you are not suposed to put a class into a title tag and it must be within a `<head>` tag.

Just remember the basic structure of a HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *and not overload you with a bunch of advanced information* We both know what the next question then will be. "why is my page's title 'undefined'?". Also you have a syntax error in your code `var h1Text = h1Element .innerHTML` (remove space between the `.` and `innerHTML`). Nxt thing,  it's bad to even use `innerHTML` here - what if the `h1` contains other HTML elements? These would appear as text in the document title.

Comment: @connexo That's not a syntax error. It's not standard practice to write it that way but it's perfectly valid to do so.

Comment: @Sean Good point! But it's not only "not standard practice", it definitely is *bad practice*.

Comment: @connexo That's a matter of opinion. Whitespace in accessing properties or chaining methods can [helpfully improve readability in ways that are recommended good practice](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#whitespace--chains).

Comment: 9999 out of 10000 developers for sure would disagree on `h1 .innerHTML`. The one that won't should be fired. The example you reference recommends a practice that always involves a line break in the white-space you suggest, and that is perfectly fine and agreeable.

Comment: @connexo of course innerHTML should not be used in the real world but this looks like his firsts lines of code, he will learn soon enough that he can and must do this things in better ways. my bad for the syntax error, i just started answering things on stackoverflow and i am not used to it yet. best regards for you mate